# IE9 scripting causing print rendering problems

Tags: internet-explorer-9

My site renders perfectly in IE9 (and in earlier IE versions, if Expression Web 4 SuperPreview is to be believed) as well in all other browsers accessible by Expression Web 4 (Firefox, Chrome, Safari, and Opera).  I use the latest versions of all browsers (updated yesterday).

It also prints reasonably in all browsers except for IE9 (Opera prints reasonably if scaled to 70%).

It prints perfectly (actually best of all browsers) in IE9 if I do not click on "Allow Blocked Content" (which, as near as I can tell from research, forces explicit approval of scripts).  I use a few simple jQuery scripts for various purposes.  If I do click on that option, however, while the page renders perfectly, the print does not render at all.  The background is in the middle, and the content is basically detached from the background and fills the whole print preview screen.  The print itself clips off content that does not happen to float on top of the portion of the page that includes the background.  I checked my IE9 options, and I do allow active scripting, which makes me wonder why the blocking pop-up is occurring at all, as well as software rendering (as opposed to GPU).

Anyone have any ideas on what may be going on?  Thanks.

Comment: I should add that I am using a background gradient, the one available on the MS gradient selector website, with a cut and paste of that CSS code.  Works perfectly, but maybe the gradient is causing the problem.  The gradient is not rendered if "Allow Blocked Content" is not clicked, and this is when printing renders properly.

Comment: I can't believe it!!  For those of you who may view this post, I commented out the CSS that is the gradient -- which I procured from a website hosted by MS itself!!  IE9 now works perfectly -- rendering and printing -- even after allowing blocked content.

Comment: Update:  It is this line of code that created the problem: -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Gradient(StartColorStr=#D4D4D4, EndColorStr=#4D4D4D)";

Comment: The above line of CSS code, which is the gradient generator for IE versions before IE10, works to produce the gradient in IE9, but also creates the print rendering problem.  I confess that this code does not come from the aforementioned MS gradient selector website, which starts with the yet-to-be-released IE10, but rather from a textbook on CSS.  Apologies to MS.

Comment: So, do I go with a nice gradient for IE9 (without the annoyance and complexities of SVG), or do I opt for the ability to print the page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that the -ms-filter gradient workaround produces unprintable webpages in IE9.  Decision: eliminate that line of code and live with a monochrome background color in IE.  Site will display gradients in all other browsers without print issues and in IE10 when it is released (one hopes).